# Is there a faster way of adding comment hashtags into both sides of a program in VSCode to make the program visually nicer to look and read from?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, comments, hashtag

Good Morning,

I've been updating my program's code by including comments that explains what each section of code does. Because of this, I decided to add hashtags on both sides of the code as well in order to make the program's code be *visually* placed within a box made up of hashtags.

For example:

BEFORE adding comments and hashtags:

```
def printInput():
    userInput = int(input("Enter your input: ")

    print("The entered user input is " + userInput + ".")

printInput()
```

AFTER adding comments and hashtags:

```
###############################################################################
# STEP 1: Create a function                                                   #
###############################################################################
# printInput is used to both ask AND display an integer input the user places #
#                                                                             #
  def printInput():                                                           #
      userInput = int(input("Enter your input: ")                             #
#                                                                             #
      print("The entered user input is " + userInput + ".")                   #
#                                                                             #
  printInput()                                                                #
###############################################################################
```

The code is going to work fine due to the fact that the lines containing the code itself DOES NOT have a hashtag placed in front of them. Only at the very end of the line (doesn't matter if the line of code is long or not). This explains why to the far left some hashtags are placed and some are not.

Is there a faster way of adding hashtag's like this into a VSCode program (Python)? An extension at least that exists? Or would I need to MANUALLY type in the hashtags myself?

And thanks!

Comment: use the method described by foozi, it will give you tooltips and intellisense explanation. And this type of style will not pass my review, it makes the stuff unreadable, a lot of unneeded clutter, refactor your program to separate input and output

Comment: if you want this type of formatting you can write a Code formatter extension, or an extension that formats a selection, or use Hypersnips

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
STEP 1: Create a function 
printInput is used to both ask AND display an integer input the user places                                                                              
'''

def printInput():                                                           
    userInput = int(input("Enter your input: ") 
    print("The entered user input is " + userInput + ".")                   
                                                                         
printInput()
```

Use ''' to add longer comments like how I showed above

If you want to make an entire line or paragraph of code, double-click or highlight the entire thing and type: '''

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But I wanted to see if my method would be possible to do instead of using '''.

I'm aiming to have my program be visually appealing, hence why the hashtags are being used.